# Emissary / Ambassador / Representative / Envoy / Delegate

Tags: word-choice

These words are all more or less interchangeable, but I'm wondering which is most distinguished. If I have a group of representatives, but some are the leaders of their groups and others are just regular members of their groups, or some are from influential groups and some are from uninfluential groups, which terms would I use to hint at who is most important?

Comment: No one is most important. (And the word is *delegate*, not *deligate*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the five words you mention, one stands out to me as being more distinguished: Ambassador, because it is most often used as an official title for a govenment official. "Representative" is the next most distinguished, at least in the US, and most states, because it is one of the elected government officials. Emissaries and envoys are somewhat less distinguished than ambassadors, in that while an Ambassador always has an official government position, an envoy or emissary might not have. A person sent by the US President to meet with Cuban representatives to unofficially discuss matters of mutual concern might be termed an envoy, or emissary of the President, but as long as the US and Cuba have no diplomatic relations, not an Ambassador.

Finally, delegate (as a noun) is most often used to designate the people elected from organization represent the organization at some other non-governmental legislative assembly. In the US, major actions of the political parties are conducted by conventions made up of delegates elected from the various state political parties.